# Celery worker working from command line but not as daemon, in a virtualenv

Tags: python, django, celery, virtualenv, celerybeat

**System Info**

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Django 1.5.5

Python 2.7.3

Celery 3.1.9

I am running this on a vagrant virtual machine (with puppet) and attempting to set up celery to run the worker as a daemon as described in the celery docs [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html) as well as the celery setup for django described [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).  I am using a virtualenv for the project located at

```
/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/myproj
```

The actual project files are located at

```
/srv/myproj
```

I have been able to start the the worker and the beat scheduler without issue when located in the /srv/myproj directory using the command line statements.

```
~/virtualenvs/myproj/bin/celery -A app beat
~/virtualenvs/myproj/bin/celery worker -A app
```

Both beat and the worker start without issue and the scheduled task is passed to the worker and executed.  The problem arises when I attempt to attempt to run them as background processes.  I am using the scripts found on the [celery github repo](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/extra/generic-init.d) in /etc/init.d/ and using the following configuration settings in my celeryd and celerybeat files located in /etc/default

```
CELERY_BIN="/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/myproj/bin/celery"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/srv/myproj"
```

Attempting to run the services as sudo with

```
sudo service celeryd start
sudo service celerybeat start
```

Causes an error message to be thrown, I believe this is because it is using the python located in usr/lib instead of the python in the virtualenv.  The error thrown is a cannot import name (the package exists in the virtualenv but not globally hence my assumption).

I also noticed on the Running the worker as a daemon it states that workers should run as unprivileged users, and that you should start workers and beat as using the multi or 
--detach command.  This way I was able to start the worker (not beat) but all the .log and .pid files are being created in my current directory instead of where I've specified in the /etc/default/celeryd config file.

Does anyone have a solution for getting celery to work in a virtualenv?  I feel like I'm really close and am overlooking some simple part of the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was eventually able to get this working by using supervisor and setting the environment variables in the [program:celery] environment option.

Comment: please take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821614/celery-daemon-production-local-config-file-without-django)